# Error deploying JSF Project in Glassfish - java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: fFeatures

Tags: jsf, glassfish, project, nosuchfileexception

I'm dispairing with this error and hope you can help me. I'm trying to deploy a JSF Project to a Glassfish Server and receive this ERROR:

```
Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: fFeatures. Please see server.log for more 
details.
```

Important to say, is that when I deploy the application on client-side (Windows) on the same Glassfish Version (4.1.1), it works properly and without any errors. But if I try to deploy it on the Glassfish (on Linux) I receive the error. To contain errors I also tried to deploy it on my Mac. >> Same Error.

I also have red possible solutions like this: "https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1026" 
It didn't help :(

Do you have any idea?

Thanks a lot.

Here is my POM.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
<artifactId>myWebApp</artifactId>
<version>1.0.7</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>myWebApp</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <!--
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.16</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-shared</artifactId>
        <version>7.6.8</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.18</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xom</groupId>
        <artifactId>xom</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.cloudbees.thirdparty/vijava -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.cloudbees.thirdparty</groupId>
        <artifactId>vijava</artifactId>
        <version>5.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.6.jre8-preview</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.39</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mortbay.jetty/jetty -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0.pre5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-security</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.3.v20170317</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mortbay.jetty/jetty-util -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0.pre5</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.16</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-scratchpad -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
        <version>3.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>3.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/fr.opensagres.xdocreport/org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/exec-maven-plugin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.icu/icu4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
        <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
        <version>59.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vmware/vijava -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vmware</groupId>
        <artifactId>vijava</artifactId>
        <version>5.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.9.v20130131</version>
            <configuration>
                <webAppConfig>
                    <contextPath>/ultima</contextPath>
                </webAppConfig>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>5</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <connectors>
                    <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                        <port>8095</port>
                    </connector>
                </connectors>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${build.sourceDirectory}</directory>
                        <targetPath>sources</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>distribute</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>build-layout</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <descriptors>
                                    <descriptor>src/assemble/layout.xml</descriptor>
                                </descriptors>
                                <finalName>${project.name}-layout-${project.version}</finalName>
                                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>build-theme</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <descriptors>
                                    <descriptor>src/assemble/theme.xml</descriptor>
                                </descriptors>
                                <finalName>${project.name}-theme-${project.version}</finalName>
                                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: Tthe JDK version is also the same. JDK 1.8

Comment: Are all those GlassFishes you mention vanilla-unzipped versions, or did were some of them modified? It seems that you have added one or more JAR libraries to the GlassFish domain you've used for development which is missing on the production instance.

Comment: They are vanilla-unziped versions. Both of them.
I downloaded it as .zip.

Comment: Does nobody have a solution?

Comment: I have now removed the most of the unused <dependencies> in the .pom-File. After building my project again it works :)